# Amateur designing a quadcopter: is it possible to use Fizzly for remote control?

Tags: bluetooth, quad-copter

I am a total amateur, so forgive me if my question is naive. I am starting to design my quadcopter, and I was wondering if it would be possible to control it via bluetooth using [Fizzly](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/fizzly/fizzly-the-first-creative-smart-tag-to-enhance-you). It would be for outdoor use, so maybe the reach could be a problem. My idea is to use the Fizzly to input command to my laptop and then send it to the copter. Basically I would like to control the copter via my arms motion. My final project would involve more than one fizzly to individually control the different motions.

Do you see any obvious limitation to this?

Do you know any source for bluetooth control where I can find useful ideas?

Comment: As you already stated yourself, bluetooth has severe range limitations. I would strongly recommend against it for flying devices. You are likely to lose control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no to this there are lots of limitations. First limitation is it would be very hard to control using motion sensing devices unless your Quadcopter is autonomous and is auto-stable in normal condition. Another thing is Fizzy project is no longer active now since It didn't receive required funding. Also if you are planing to use 2 or more Fizzy devices that would mean to use 2 or more Bluetooth module in the Quadcopter also.

Alternative, you can use the [Fin ring Project](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/fin-wearable-ring-make-your-palm-as-numeric-keypad-and-gesture-interface) which is also similar like Fizzy. But again the overall project will be like lots of lines of code and am not sure whether the device is available in market yet.

The best option is to use your SmartPhone as the controlling device, it has the motion sensors and you just need to create the corresponding ios or android App to send control signals via bluetooth. All you need to do is use an XBee or Zigbee Bluetooth Module in your Quadcopter Board such that it is paired to your smartphone. So here also u can control the copter using hand signals using your Smartphone.

Comment: yep, no fizzy anyway...

Comment: Did you complete your project or somehow managed to figure it out??

Comment: well, i was on a "preparing myself to receive the fizzy" stage, so now i have to change approach completely...

Comment: Ok, Cool.... Best of luck for your project...:)